# Converting an array of polygon points to an array of shapes with holes - js

Tags: javascript, recursion, polygon

A JSFiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/X8427/1/

I have an array of polygons like this:

```
var pts = 
//array of shapes
[
    //array of shape coordinates
    [
        {
            X: 10,
            Y: 15
        },
        {
            X: 10,
            Y: 20
        },
        {
            X: 15,
            Y: 20
        },
        {
            X: 15,
            Y: 15
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            X: 11,
            Y: 16
        },
        {
            X: 11,
            Y: 19
        },
        {
            X: 14,
            Y: 19
        },
        {
            X: 14,
            Y: 16
        }
    ]
];
```

None of the polygons edges overlap, but I need to find out which, if any, of the polygons created have holes inside another; So this input array would end up looking like this:

```
[
    //array of shapes
    {
        //coordinates of outer shape
        outer: [
                    {
                        X: 10,
                        Y: 15
                    },
                    {
                        X: 10,
                        Y: 20
                    },
                    {
                        X: 15,
                        Y: 20
                    },
                    {
                        X: 15,
                        Y: 15
                    }
               ]
         //array of holes with in the outer shape
         holes: [
                    //array of hole coordinates
                    [
                         {
                             X: 11,
                             Y: 16
                         },
                         {
                             X: 11,
                             Y: 19
                         },
                         {
                             X: 14,
                             Y: 19
                         },
                         {
                             X: 14,
                             Y: 16
                         }
                    ]
               ]
     }
]
```

As the edges of the polygons don't overlap, I can check if only one of the polygons points are inside another polygon with this function:

```
    function pointInPoly(poly, pt){
        for(var c = false, i = -1, l = poly.length, j = l - 1; ++i < l; j = i)
            ((poly[i].Y <= pt.Y && pt.Y < poly[j].Y) || (poly[j].Y <= pt.Y && pt.Y < poly[i].Y))
            && (pt.X < (poly[j].X - poly[i].X) * (pt.Y - poly[i].Y) / (poly[j].Y - poly[i].Y) + poly[i].X)
            && (c = !c);
        return c;
    }
```

like so:

```
var shapes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < pts.length; i++) {
    if (pts[i]) {
        var shape = {outer: pts[i], holes: []};

        for (var j = 0; j < pts.length; j++) {
            if (i != j && pointInPoly(pts[i], pts[j][0])) {
                shape.holes.push(pts[j]);
                pts[j] = false;
            }
        }

        shapes.push(shape);
    }
}
console.log(shapes);
```

This works for the test data, but if there is a third polygon inside the hole, then it will be added as a hole to the outer shape, but actually it's a second shape which could have holes of its own. How can I get this working recursively so i end up with an array of all the separate shapes and holes?

Comment: Does each shape only ever have one "hole"?

Comment: no, they can have multiple holes

Comment: I guess your best solution would be to only test if a shape was inside another, if neither of them are already holes.

Could use indexOf() to check if the holes array already contains the currently tested shapes. :)